# Rails 3.1 Plugin Generator and Fixtures Not Working in Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just converting an old gem to use the Rails 3.1 plugin template (`rails new plugin ...`) and after generating a basic 'dummy' app with a few models and controllers I get:

```
undefined method `images' for #<ImagesControllerTest:0x007fac92d1ea48>
```

After running the tests. This appears to be an issue with the fixtures methods not loading correctly. I followed the standard practice for getting this setup; do I need do anything else to get the dummy application to include fixtures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. It appears that using `rails plugin new` does not include in `test_helper.rb`:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
end
```

Adding fixes.